# How to translate "Устранить замечания" to English?

Tags: перевод

I am going to "fix comments" or "eliminate notes" or "remove remarks"?

I think that those phrases changes the meaning of "Устранить замечания".

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately this question is not about Russian language, so it's off-topic.
You can try however your luck on English SE - in this case the question still need to be edited - to make it clear to English speakers what phrase they are supposed to translate.

Comment: ***устранить замечания*** is a poorly worded phrase because it mixes  remarks about defects with actual defects, the person responsible can remove/repair defects but not remarks made by someone else... the rendering you have accepted actually means ***отреагировать на замечания*** that is to take action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, "устранить замечания" usually doesn't simply mean to get rid of the remarks. You are eliminating them by doing something, presumably by improving things that were remarked on. What you are doing in this case can be called *addressing* the remarks.

"Address the remarks" keeps both the intended meaning and the object of the original phrase (замечания – remarks).

Comment: Looks good. I found this example "You are requested to take necessary action to address the remarks mentioned above"